# Determining Razor Web Page Hierarchy

Tags: .net, asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have a custom view page class in an ASP.NET Razor web site (not MVC).  What I need to be able to do is determine the child pages that are within the parent page.  Is there any way to determine this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by child and parent? Layouts? Partials?

Comment: View (parent) and partial view (child).

Comment: How do you call the partial view? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be used, but you might be able to.

```
var pageHierachy = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
```

It will get the path of the page you're currently on. You might be able to play around with it to make it do exactly what you want it to.

Good luck :)